# how can I convert .py file to .blend

Tags: python, model, blender

I have recently downloaded some models for blender but when I unzipped it the file was in .py format I want to add them to my project but I cant I tried "open in" method but no results..... can anyone tell me how to fix it

Comment: `py` files are not models, its python code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't appear to be a question about programming. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This site is not Blender tech support.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change its format from .py to .blend

you can do this with help of notepad.

open .py file in notepad and save as .blend format.

Comment: actually it dont work

Comment: Blender just says that this file format doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what the content of the .py file is.
A .py file is a python script, and you can't just "convert" it in a blender file. They are two different things.
It might be the case that the .py file is just a text file (saved as a .py file) that contains the coordinates of a mesh. In this case, just change .py in .obj and import it in blender.